# What's the difference between {} and [] in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, syntax

```
>> A={1 2;2 3}

A = 

    [1]    [2]
    [2]    [3]
>> A=[1 2;2 3]

A =

     1     2
     2     3
```

It seems to me they are essentially the same thing?

Comment: related 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055015/difference-between-accessing-cell-elements-using-and-curly-braces-vs-par

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between cell and matrix in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000923/difference-between-cell-and-matrix-in-matlab)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`{}`'s are for cells. `[]`'s are for arrays/matrices.

Comment: What's the difference between cells and array/matrix?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html#br1xnp2-1

Answer (score 8):

`[]` is an array-related operator. An array can be of any type - array of numbers, char array (string), struct array or cell array. All elements in an array must be of the **same type!**

Example: `[1,2,3,4]`

`{}` is a type. Imagine you want to put items of different type into an array - a number and a string. This is possible with a trick - first put each item into a container `{}` and then make an array with these containers - cell array.

Example: `[{1},{'Hallo'}]` with shorthand notation `{1, 'Hallo'}`

It is unnecessary to put objects of the same type (doubles) into a cell array like in your example.

Answer (score 4):

No. They are not at all the same thing. The only aspect that is the same is the resulting shape.

An array (that which you build with []) is something you can use to do linear algebra. One number in each element.

```
A = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9];
[3 5 7]*A*[2 3 5]'
ans =
   915
```

A cell array is a general container, that will hold any object, any matlab variable entirely in each cell. Thus we can create a cell array composed of elements of any shape and size.

```
C = {'The' 'quick' 'brown' 'fox' 'jumps' 'over' 'the' 'lazy' 'dog'};
```

C is a cell array with 9 elements in it. We can put any class of variable in there.

```
C = {'asfghhrstyjtysj', 1:5, magic(4), sqrt(-1)}
C = 
    'asfghhrstyjtysj'    [1x5 double]    [4x4 double]    [0 +          1i]
```

We could even create a cell array where each cell contains only a single scalar number. But there would be no real point in doing so, as we cannot do arithmetic operations using cell arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If you relate it to object oriented programming, 
cells {} are like objects and [] is for arrays

Answer (score 1):

Elements of different data types which get inside `{}` become cells or elements of data type `cell`.  Elements inside `[]` retain their data type and make an array of that data type. Few examples below:

```
p = ['my', 'string'];
q = [int8(1), int8(2), int8(3)];
r = [0.11, 0.22, 0.33];
s = {'my', 'string'};
t = {1,2,3};
u = {0.11, 0.22, 0.33};
v = {int8(1), int8(2), int8(3)};

>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  p         1x8                16  char                
  q         1x3                 3  int8                
  r         1x3                24  double              
  s         1x2               240  cell                
  t         1x3               360  cell                
  u         1x3               360  cell                
  v         1x3               339  cell
```