# How do concatenation and indexing differ for cells and arrays in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, cell, concatenation

I am a little confused about the usage of cells and arrays in MATLAB and would like some clarification on a few points. Here are my observations:

1. An array can dynamically adjust its own memory to allow for a dynamic number of elements, while cells seem to not act in the same way:

   ```
   a=[]; a=[a 1]; b={}; b={b 1};
   ```
2. Several elements can be retrieved from cells, but it doesn't seem like they can be from arrays:

   ```
   a={'1' '2'}; figure; plot(...); hold on; plot(...); legend(a{1:2});   
   b=['1' '2']; figure; plot(...); hold on; plot(...); legend(b(1:2));
   %# b(1:2) is an array, not its elements, so it is wrong with legend.
   ```

Are these correct? What are some other different usages between cells and array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) can be a little tricky since you can use the `[]`, `()`, *and* `{}` syntaxes in various ways for [creating](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html), [concatenating](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combine-cell-arrays.html), and [indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) them, although they each do different things. Addressing your two points:

1. To grow a cell array, you can use one of the following syntaxes:

   ```
   b = [b {1}];     % Make a cell with 1 in it, and append it to the existing
                    %   cell array b using []
   b = {b{:} 1};    % Get the contents of the cell array as a comma-separated
                    %   list, then regroup them into a cell array along with a
                    %   new value 1
   b{end+1} = 1;    % Append a new cell to the end of b using {}
   b(end+1) = {1};  % Append a new cell to the end of b using ()
   ```
2. When you index a cell array with `()`, it returns a subset of cells in a cell array. When you index a cell array with `{}`, it returns a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of the cell contents. For example:

   ```
   b = {1 2 3 4 5};  % A 1-by-5 cell array
   c = b(2:4);       % A 1-by-3 cell array, equivalent to {2 3 4}
   d = [b{2:4}];     % A 1-by-3 numeric array, equivalent to [2 3 4]
   ```

   For `d`, the `{}` syntax extracts the contents of cells 2, 3, and 4 as a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), then uses `[]` to collect these values into a numeric array. Therefore, `b{2:4}` is equivalent to writing `b{2}, b{3}, b{4}`, or `2, 3, 4`.

   With respect to your call to [`legend`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html), the syntax `legend(a{1:2})` is equivalent to `legend(a{1}, a{2})`, or `legend('1', '2')`. Thus *two* arguments (two separate characters) are passed to `legend`. The syntax `legend(b(1:2))` passes a single argument, which is a 1-by-2 string `'12'`.

Answer (score 4):

Every cell array is an array! [From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654786/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-matlab):

`[]` is an array-related operator. An array can be of any type - array of numbers, char array (string), struct array or cell array. All elements in an array must be of the **same type!**

Example: `[1,2,3,4]`

`{}` is a type. Imagine you want to put items of different type into an array - a number and a string. This is possible with a trick - first put each item into a container `{}` and then make an array with these containers - cell array.

Example: `[{1},{'Hallo'}]` with shorthand notation `{1, 'Hallo'}`