# how to store heterogenous objects in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need to make an image pyramid in matlab for one of my assignments. Though there are inbuilt methods to get the individual images in the pyramid, I am confused about how to store the handles to the images. (I don't have much experience with matlab)

Arrays don't work, since the images in the pyramid are of different size. I am looking for something like a list in .net, or arraylist in Java. In [MATLAB linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413860/matlab-linked-list), they say that you can use the standard Java classes, but matlab hung when i tried to use java's arraylist. So, what is the best way to store a collection of heterogeneous data(or handles?) in matlab?

EDIT1 : The code which is not working:

```
im0 = imread('..\lenna-lg.jpg'); //im0 = 480*480*3 array
im1 = impyramid(im0,'reduce');  //im1 = 240*240*3 array
pyramid = [ im0, im1 ];  //Error : Error using ==> horzcat
                         //CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with some further searching, i have found out what is called a cell, which basically seems to be a heterogeneous array. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662964/cell-and-array-in-matlab). So the following code is working now

```
im0 = imread('..\lenna-lg.jpg'); //im0 = 480*480*3 array
im1 = impyramid(im0,'reduce');  //im1 = 240*240*3 array
cell = [ {im0}, {im1} ];  //cell = 1*2 cell
ans = cell{1};            //ans = 480*480*3 array
```

This seems to be a very convenient way to handle heterogeneous data. Is this the right way to go about this?

Comment: Either cell arrays or structures are the two best options for storing multiple data types in a single variable.

Comment: As @Edric suggests, cell arrays and structures should be on your reading list very soon.  Later you should study containers and objects.

Comment: A couple of suggestions: 1) Don't use the name `cell` for a variable, since this will shadow the built-in function [CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html). 2) Your third line can be written in a more conventional way as `cellArray = {im0, im1};`.