# Simple indexing in a cell array

Tags: matlab

I've constructed a simple Matlab cell array:

```
d1 =
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

d2 =
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6

d3 =
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7

d = 
[5x1 double]
[5x1 double]
[5x1 double]

clear d1 d2 d3;
```

How do I access the original array d1 data inside cell array d, after d1 is cleared? If I do:

```
>> d(1,:)
ans = 
[5x1 double]
```

but what I want to do is issue this command:

```
d(what indexing goes here?)
```

and have it return:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Here's a related question that you may be interested in: [How do concatenation and indexing differ for cells and arrays in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662964/how-do-concatenation-and-indexing-differ-for-cells-and-arrays-in-matlab)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out:

```
d{1,1,:}
```

returns back the original d1 information.

Comment: `d{1}` would probably work just as well.  `d` is a 1x5 cell array, so `d{n}` is the contents of one of those cells.  (`d(n)` is a single cell, aka a 1x1 cell array, not the numeric array you were trying to get.)  You can even use multiple subscripts: `d{2}(3)` gets the third element of the array in the second cell.