# How worked visibilitychange?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a question:

```js
window.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function(e) {
  console.log(window.uidd)
  window.uidd = window.uidd || (new Date).getTime() + Math.random()
  console.log(window.uidd)
})
```

But if you open console and first time you get:

```
undefined
124124214124124.124

window.uidd // undefined
```

Why is that so last string is `undefined`?

Comment: Because the first time you console.log it, it is undefined...you only assign it a value in the second line if your event listener. Why are you expecting it to be anything else than `undefined`?

Comment: @msanford it is not my question

Comment: The last string is not `undefined` when I test your code sample. Is there code missing?

Comment: @msanford first line with init page always undefined, second after init have value. But after page load open console, and try get window.uidd

Comment: @msanford in my chrome last line always undefined, after load

Comment: @msanford may be new version chrome bug

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to make this an answer only because I cannot attach screen shots to comments, but I do not see this behaviour.

1. I confirm that the `window.uuid` variable does not exist on `window`.
2. I add the event listener, and get the expected first `undefined` from registering it.
3. Then I click *out* of the tab (the first `visibilitychange` event), and get the second `undefined` and the value set for `window.uuid`, both logged from the listener.
4. I click back into the tab, firing the second `visibilitychange` event, and get the uuid logged twice.
5. Typing `window.uuid` into the console returns the global uuid value.

[image]

I suspect the confusion may lay in the way you are attaching the event listener.

EDIT:

With the following test page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function(e) {
            console.dir(window);
            console.log(window.uidd)
            window.uidd = window.uidd || (new Date).getTime() + Math.random()
            console.log(window.uidd)
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I do see this behaviour. You need to access the property using `this.uuid`, rather than `window.uuid`, even though simply typing `window` will show the `.uuid` property.

Curiously, when I replace your test with this *static assignment*:

```
window.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function(e) {
    window.foo = window.foo || "bar";
})
```

it *does work*, and I can see the expected value of `window.foo` directly in the console.

I, too, am curious, and [asked the Chrome team](https://chromiumdev.slack.com/archives/C051KSB4E/p1506374432000162). I'll update this answer if someone from there doesn't answer directly.

Comment: If you added listener in console yes that work. Try added listener in script block. After that when listener already initilize window.uidd must have value, but u can checked it is not be Truth

Comment: @ЮраПанарин Updated.

Comment: it is so strange behavior

Comment: @ЮраПанарин I agree; my apologies, that is why I did not understand your interesting question at first. I did not expect this behaviour either.

Comment: it is my English skills :)

Comment: @msanford You [voted to reopen](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/17440408) [a duplicate in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407958/indexing-rules-for-extracting-sub-arrays-from-a-cell-array). You were wrong, and deciding whether the dupe is relevant needs domain knowledge. Please chose "skip" in the review queues in case of duplicates unless you are absolutely sure. Feel free to flag this comment as "no longer needed" once you've read it. Thanks.