# What is the difference between cell and matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

What is the difference between cell (i.e. with `{ }`) and matrix (i.e. with `[ ]`) in Matlab?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are several differences between a cell array and a matrix in MATLAB:

- A cell array may contain any arbitrary type of element in each cell; while a matrix requires the types of its elements to be homogeneous i.e. of the same type.
- As far as memory layout goes, all elements of a matrix are laid out contiguously in memory, while a cell array contains pointers to each element of the array. This can be important when considering things like cache locality for high performance code.
- The flip side of point 2 is that when you resize a matrix every element in the matrix must be copied over to the newly allocated memory area, but in case of a cell array only a list of pointers needs to copied over. Depending on the size and type of elements you're storing, this might mean cell arrays are much faster to resize.

---

To illustrate the differences in memory layout, let's consider a simple example:

```
A = [10 20 30 40];
```

Here MATLAB creates a new matrix variable named A, allocates enough memory to hold 4 doubles (32 bytes, assuming 8 byte doubles) and assigns this memory to a pointer that points to the *real* part of A. (If you create a matrix of complex numbers, memory is allocated for the *imaginary* part also, and a separate pointer points to this memory area).

Now let's create a cell array that holds these elements:

```
B = cell(1, 4);
B{1,1} = 10;
B{1,2} = 20;
B{1,3} = 30;
B{1,4} = 40;
```

When MATLAB executes the first statement, it creates a cell array that contains 4 pointers, each of which can point to an arbitrary type. So `B` is already using 16 bytes (assuming 32-bit pointers).
The next line creates a 1x1 matrix containing the value 10 and assigns it to the first cell array element. The process here is similar to the one I described above for creation of a 1x4 matrix, except that the memory allocated is only large enough to hold one double (8 bytes). This is repeated for each of the remaining 3 statements. So, at the bare minimum, the second example uses `16 + 8 x 4 = 48` bytes.

Note that each variable in MATLAB also includes memory overhead for a structure called an *mxArray* that stores information such as dimension, data type and a lot more about that variable. I've ignored this overhead for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: A couple things... It's a little over-specific to say that a cell array like B is storing pointers per se. Conceptually, cells are like pointers, but Matlab doesn't document how they're implemented inside `mxArray`. We just know it stores something with some overhead in there. Matlab will tell you something about how much overhead: do `a = []; c = {a}; whos`, and Matlab will report some bytes used by c. I think that's about how much overhead there is per mxarray.

Comment: ...And the fact that it reports it that way, combined with looking at addresses in the debugger and the MAT file format and so on, suggests to me that the cell mxArrays might actually be directly storing C arrays of the mxArray structure (the header part of it), instead of pointers.

Comment: Also, I know this is nitpicky, but it's each primitive or composite array *value* in Matlab that has an mxArray, not each variable. B is a variable. It holds a 4-long cell array, and each cell element contains a double array. So B's data structure has 5 mxArrays in it. This is why cells and structs can end up using a lot of overhead, which you can approximate using the per-mxarray overhead suggested by `whos`.

Comment: @AndrewJanke I did make generalizations in my answer. I agree, it is each *value* (I don't think that is the correct term either, but can't think of a better one), and not *variable*, that has its own mxArray header. And MATLAB doesn't document anything about internal representations of types, other than allude to the existence of the mxArray, call it an opaque type and leave it at that. That part about a cell array type containing an array of headers, instead of pointers to each header, is news to me, glad you commented on that.

Comment: Yeah, the mxArray type is opaque and undocumented. (And could change between versions.) My understanding of it is an educated guess based on the External Interfaces doco for C mx functions, the pre-7.3 binary MAT file format (which _is_ fully documented), and looking at the mxArray memory in MEX files and a debugger. I suspect the in-memory layout mxArray looks a lot like the MAT file layout, and peeking around in memory at runtime has been consistent with that. And yeah, _value_ isn't quite right either. Maybe _array_?