# How to count the number of overlapping blocks in an Image

Tags: matlab

I have a 512X512 size of image and I have made 4x4 overlapping blocks for the entire image.How can i count the number of overlapping blocks and save it in an Array in matlab.
I have done like below for 4x4 overlapping blocks. Now how to count the no of blocks and store it using an Array.

```
[e f] = size(outImg);
l=0;
for i=2:e-2
    for j=2:f-2
        H =double(outImg((i-1:i+2),(j-1:j+2)));
        eval(['out_' num2str(l) '=H']);
        l=l+1
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and its expected output?

Comment: I have edited the code.If u apply the code on any image ,you can find in the command window about,how 4x4 non-overlapping blocks are formed for the entire image.

Comment: Why do you want to count them? You can calculate the number of blocks. How do you want to store them? My first guess would be: create a 3D matrix of size e-3 X f-3 x 4 and store the values in the third dimension?

Comment: Yes i want to calculate the no of blocks and store it

Comment: At the end of this run, is `l` the number of blocks?

Comment: Yes ,i dint notice l will be the no of blocks.@Cape Codeim trying for inverse halftoning using LUT ,for which i ve to follow procedure to write code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand the question, you want to know how many blocks of 4x4 can fit in the image, and then store them.

Calculating the number of blocks is trivial, in the code that you give as example, `l` is the number of element counted. Of course, that its value is deterministic (determined by `f` and `e`). No need to loop over them to get the value of the count.

```
count = (f-3)*(e-3);
```

If you want to save the values in an array (assuming that you mean here a matrix and not a cell array) you need to decide how to represent it, you can store it as a 4D `e-3 x f-3 x 4 x 4` matrix (as @Steffen suggested), or as a 3D `4 x 4 x count` matrix, I think that the later is more intuitive. In any case you should assign the memory for the matrix in advance and not on the fly:

```
[e f] = size(outImg);
count = (f-3)*(e-3);
outMat = zeros(4,4,count); % assign the memory for the matrix
l = 0;
for i=2:e-2
    for j=2:f-2
        l = l + 1;
        outMat(:,:,l) = double(outImg((i-1:i+2),(j-1:j+2)));
    end;
end;
```

The number of blocks is stored as both `count` and `l`, but calculating `count` in advance allows to assign the needed memory in advance, the `i` block is stored as `outMat(:,:,i)`.

An implementation using the 4D matrix would be:

```
[e f] = size(outImg);
count = (f-3)*(e-3);
outMat = zeros((f-3),(e-3),4,4); % assign the memory for the matrix
for i=2:e-2
    for j=2:f-2
        outMat(i,j,:,:) = double(outImg((i-1:i+2),(j-1:j+2)));
    end;
end;
```

In this case, `l` isn't needed and each block (indexed `i`,`j`) is located at `outMat(i,j,:,:)`

Regarding cell array vs. a matrix, since a matrix requires a continuous place in the memory, you may want to consider using a cell array instead of a matrix. A 512x512x4 matrix of doubles requires (assuming 8 Byte representation) 8MB (512*512*8*4 = 8*1024*1024). If the dimensions were bigger, or if you are strapped for (continuous) memory a cell array may be a better solution. You can read more about the difference at [Difference between cell and matrix in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000923/difference-between-cell-and-matrix-in-matlab).

The implementation would be very similar.

```
[e f] = size(outImg);
count = (f-3)*(e-3);
outArray = cell(1,count);
l = 0;
for i=2:e-2
    for j=2:f-2
        l = l + 1;
        outArray{1,l} = double(outImg((i-1:i+2),(j-1:j+2)));
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple.  Each loop iteration will access 1 overlapping block in your image.  All you have to do is count how many times the loop iterates, which is `((e-2) - 2 + 1) x ((f - 2) - 2 + 1) = (e - 3) x (f - 3)`.  There's no need to keep a loop iteration variable.

---

Minor note.  Under no circumstances should you use `eval` unless absolutely necessary.  The MATLAB gods will smite any offenders swiftly.  That code to assign a new variable to each increment of `l` is absolutely unnecessary.  If you were to have 10000 overlapping blocks, you would have 10000 variables.  You can just simply take a look at `l` at the end and this would tell you how many overlapping blocks you have.

**Remove that line of code.  WE HATES IT.  IT BURNS US.**

[image]

---

See [this post by Loren Shure for more details](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/) on why using `eval` is bad.

Comment: Thanks a lot All of you.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1-D case, the correct formula to estimate the total number of overlapping blocks is:

(#Of_blocks) = (#Image_width - #Block_width) / (#Block_width - #Block_overlap) + 1

If the result is not integer you just take the floor of #Of_blocks, this means that the whole interval can't be covered using that setup.