# How to store the 2D image pixels into 1d array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing

I want to store the m(i,j) values in a 1D array of 2 rows. 1st row wd be the m(ij) counter and 2nd row w'd be m(ij) value for each iteration.How can i do that,? Please Help.
want to convert 2D to 1D array like array(2,count).

```
     [e,f] = size(outImg);    
    m = zeros(e,f);    
    counter=0
    w = [1 2 4 8; 16 32 64 128; 256 512 1024 2048; 4096 8192 16384 32768];    
    for i = 1:e-3    
        for j = 1:f-3    
            I = double(outImg((i:i+3),(j:j+3)));  
            counter=counter+1;  
            m(i,j) = sum(sum(I .* w));   
        end     
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the quickest way (though not necessarily the most efficient, but most compatible with your code...) would be to allocate a 2D array and populate this array at each iteration.  Referencing [my previous post to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866247/how-to-count-the-number-of-overlapping-blocks-in-an-image), the total number of times this loop iterates is `(e-3) x (f-3)` times.  Therefore, allocate a 2D array like how you said in your post.  Only this time, replace `count` with `(e-3)*(f-3)`.

Something like the following:

```
[e,f] = size(outImg);    
m = zeros(e,f);    
counter=0;
counts = zeros(2, (e-3)*(f-3)); %// NEW
w = [1 2 4 8; 16 32 64 128; 256 512 1024 2048; 4096 8192 16384 32768];    
for i = 1:e-3    
    for j = 1:f-3    
        I = double(outImg((i:i+3),(j:j+3)));  
        counter=counter+1;  
        m(i,j) = sum(sum(I .* w));  
        counts(:,counter) = [counter; m(i,j)]; %// NEW
    end     
end
```

Therefore, you will have a 2D array called `counts` of size `2 x (e-3)*(f-3)`, where each column denotes the "iteration number" and the value of the summation for each pixel neighbourhood at each iteration in the loop.

Comment: Thank You.. It works.But its so slow,because the counter value is too high. how can u count the counter as just doing (e-3)*(f-3).

Comment: @SanghamitraTripathy - You're welcome :) Please accept my answer whenever you're able to... if I have helped.  Good luck!

Comment: (1) *"The counter value is too high"* is not the reason why your code is slow.  The main reason why is due to the `for` loop itself. Usually, `for` loops are very inefficient in MATLAB.  If you want that code to run faster, you'll need to vectorize it.  I can certainly vectorize your code for you, but you should probably make another post.  It's not within the scope of your question.  (2) *"how can you count the counter as just doing (e-3)*(f-3)"*. Read my post I linked to you.  You've asked the same question last week, and accepted an answer. Do you not read the answers to your own questions?

Comment: Yes of course i had accepted the answer:-).i got the exact counter value, but my doubt was how it was just substracting 3 from [e,f] gives the exact count

Comment: @SanghamitraTripathy - It's very simple.  The outer `for` loop executes exactly `e-3` times because it iterates from 1 to `e-3`.  For each outer iteration of the outer `for` loop, the inner `for` loop executes `f-3` times because that loop iterates from 1 to `f-3`.  Therefore, the inner `for` loop gets repeated `e-3` times in total due to the outer `for` loop calling the inner `for` loop that many times, and so the total number of iterations all together is `(e-3) x (f-3)`.  I don't know how else to simplify it for you.

Comment: @SanghamitraTripathy Please upvote as well as accepting. You didn't do that on the accepted answer to the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866247/how-to-count-the-number-of-overlapping-blocks-in-an-image) either.

Comment: @kkuilla - I wish the OP could upvote, but they can't :(.  They don't have enough reputation.