# Unintended infinite loop with `imshow`

Tags: matlab, for-loop, image-processing, infinite-loop

```
for i = [I, J, K];
   imshow(i);
end
```

`I`, `J`, `K` are 16-bit images.

The script keeps trying to pump out the images (but doesn't) and gets into an infinite loop.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store multiple images in a matrix if they have the same sizes.
However, You should store the images in a `cell` if they have different sizes. This method is less messier because you don't need to worry about how to extract them later.

define a cell with the size equal to the number of images.

```
numImages = 3;
Images = cell(1,numImage);
```

Store an image `I` into a cell:

```
Images{1,1} = I;
```

Now go over the images and show them

```
for ii = 1:3
    imshow(Images{1,ii});
end
```

**Example:**

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
J = imread('peppers.png');
K = imread('snowflakes.png');
Images = cell(1,3);
Images{1,1} = I;
Images{1,2} = J;
Images{1,3} = K;
for ii=1:numel(Images)
    figure;imshow(Images{1,ii});
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding as to which point exactly you are missing/what is happening here: Using square brackets works like a concatenation here. So the line

```
i = [I, J, K]    % separated with commas or spaces for horzcat
i = [I; J; K]    % separated with semi-colons for vertcat
```

does the same as [`horzcat`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) or [`vertcat`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html):

```
i = horzcat(I, J, K);
i = vertcat(I, J, K);
```

Let's say `I, J, K` are 64x64 gray valued images. A (horizontal) concatenation will create a 64x192 matrix. The `for` loop will go through your matrix column-wise, which means it will extract a 64x1 vector 192-times (or much more often for larger images, which might feel like "infinite"). Displaying only a vector with `imshow()` won't show anything.

As already pointed out, using cells is a more flexible way to store images. When using arrays you have to handle each dimension (and this only works if your images are equal in size):

```
sizeImage = size(I);    % assume all img are same size (as I)
numImages = 3;          % needed for allocating array

% init array for imgs and fill images into array: e.g. 64x64x3
imageArray = zeros([sizeImage numImages]);

imageArray(:,:,1) = I;  % :,: selects all elements of a dimension
imageArray(:,:,2) = J;   
imageArray(:,:,3) = K;

for n = 1:numImages                         % iterate over image index
    figure; imshow(imageArray(:,:,n));      % n = 1, 2 ... , numImages 
end                                         % is used for position in imageArray
```

Using the colon `:` when accessing arrays/cells selects all elements of a dimension. E.g. `imageArray(:,:,n)` will select all elements of first and second dimension, corresponding to a 64x64 image. For RGB images an array with 3 images will be 64x64x3x3 and you'll have to use `imageArray(:,:,:,n)` to select all three color channels.

Note that using `for i = img_array` won't work, as this will give vectors again.

E.g. for `img_array`: 64x64x5 (five 64x64 gray-valued images), this will iterate over all but one dimensions (and assign the remaining dim to `i`): `img_array(:,1,1)`, `img_array(:,2,1)`, `img_array(:,3,1)`, ..., `img_array(:,1,2)`, `img_array(:,2,2)` ..., `img_array(:,64,5)` and will again produce 64*3 = 192 vectors for `i`.

As was already pointed out, if you have variable image sizes, using cell arrays is the way. You may want to consult: [Difference between cell and matrix in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000923/difference-between-cell-and-matrix-in-matlab)